# Absolutely hiding a file or a folder

Tags: 14.04, files, filemanager, hidden-files

Renaming the file  with adition of **.filename Eg ".algosig"** is not efficient I found it visible after pressing CTRL+H. Aren't there other ways which makes it invisible even after pressing CTRL + H. **Total Hiding**

Comment: But then how would you access it?

Comment: Why don't you just use something like truecrypt and encrypt the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you are trying to do sounds a lot like **steganography**, which is a rather advanced version of the technique of labelling a tape of secret files with something inconspicuous such as "Gov promo 1989".

In other words, the trick is to masquerade the **information as noise** in a different file, which won't easily get noticed unless you *know* it's hidden in there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

There are various tools for that, and you might want to have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/95877/steganography-software

Then there is this trick, mainly interesting because it relies on the often forgotten fact that headers are not to be assumed to always tell the truth: http://www.unixmen.com/steganography-in-ubuntu-hide-your-files-inside-an-image/

That said, I'm not sure if it's a great idea if your objective is a degree of **actual security.**

I would **discourage even considering it** unless you know *very very well* what you are doing.

Storing the information on a removable drive and physically locking it into a safe *might* be a step up − or a giant step down if, for example, your host machines somehow caches and indexes files on removable drivers.

All in all the best advice I feel like giving you, *if you are aiming for security* (as opposed to fun/experimentation) is: **forget it**.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your end goal is.

If its security your after you need to look in to [Unix file permissions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) or maybe even file encryption.

Hiding a file provides no measure of security.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could make the containing directory owned by somebody else (eg root) and disable others' read permissions on it:

```
$ sudo mkdir --mode 700 lockbox
$ ls lockbox/
ls: cannot open directory lockbox/: Permission denied
```

But you'll have to be root to enter it. With that in mind, you would do as well to just use `/root`. Anybody with `sudo` access can view the directory but it's probably better than nothing.

Comment: N.B. Don't run `nautilus` (or most other GUI programs) as root with `sudo` to view the folder - use `gksu` or similar if you need a GUI program otherwise bits of your home directory become owned by root...

Comment: Oh, one other thought - if the disk is unencrypted it can still be read from outside the OS

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as Completely Hidden files. The point of hidden files are to hide from the user all the "ugly" system files.

If there was no way of seeing it, there would be no point, surely?

Comment: Try `ls /root` - do those count as 'hidden'? :)

Comment: @Wilf, no, just instead of Ctrl+H it is your sudo password...

Comment: Ctrl+H doesn't need password though... A big vault underground doesn't count as hidden if you can find the map + key (etc)

Comment: Hmm yeah, I suppose. Still not convinced that root is "hidden" as such though. I suppose it's just different opinions :)